# flutter ffmpeg-kit-flutter return code 1 while audio cancelling

Tags: android, flutter, ffmpeg

ffmpeg-kit-flutter getting return code 1 while audio noise cancelling

i am using command

"-y -i "$testAudio"  -af "highpass=f=500, lowpass=f=9000"  $newPath";

also tried

'-i $testAudio -af afftdn ${f.path}'